# SQL Keeping count of occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-server-2012

I've the following problem I need to solve in SQL.

Let's say that I have a table with 2 columns:

```
    Date | Code
    --------
    0    | 25
    1    | 22
    2    | 23
    3    | 25
    4    | 23
    5    | 21
```

And I need to keep a count of them, as the Date is relevant for me. So, let's say that I would need to produce something like this:

```
    Date | Code | Count
    --------------------
    0    | 25   |   1
    1    | 22   |   1
    2    | 23   |   1
    3    | 25   |   2
    4    | 23   |   2
    5    | 21   |   1
```

Thanks in advance,

PS: I'm implementing it in MSSQL 2012.

Regards.

Comment: You are adding a column to your table, right? You can do that either through the SQL Server Management Studio GUI or via ALTER TABLE. You can also put a default value on the column, such as 1. You probably shouldn't call the column "Count", though, since that is a reserved word and means something else. Maybe use column names with some prefix, like ThisDate, ThisCode, and ThisCount?

Comment: What version of sql server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest (and probably most efficient) approach is to use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT [Date], Code, [Count] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY [Date])
 FROM dbo.YourTableName
 ORDER BY [Date];
```

For fun, you can also solve it this way in SQL Server 2012. If `Date` is unique:

```
SELECT [Date], Code, [Count] = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY [Date]
  RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
 FROM dbo.YourTable
 ORDER BY [Date];
```

Or more simply:

```
SELECT [Date], Code, [Count] = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY [Date])
 FROM dbo.YourTable
 ORDER BY [Date];
```

If `Date` is not unique, and if you don't want ties (same count for identical combinations of date+code), you need to use the more expensive `ROWS`, which uses on on-disk spool:

```
SELECT [Date], Code, [Count] = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY [Date]
  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
 FROM dbo.YourTable
 ORDER BY [Date];
```

You may want to try each of these options on your table to see what the performance is like.

Comment: @bluefeet you mean if it is SQL Server 2000? Then you'd have to use slow methods.

Comment: Yes or even MySql (I know its tagged sql server), just wondering how this could efficiently be performed.

Comment: @bluefeet sorry, I have no idea what the appropriate syntax would be for MySQL, since I don't think it has very good support for window functions. Possibly the slow methods there as well.

Comment: No problem, I was just wondering if there is an efficient way without windowing function.

Comment: @bluefeet not that I know of in SQL Server - all of the approaches that work in SQL Server 2000 have the same non-linear scaling issue. No idea about MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, something that I may have forgotten to include is that I do not have the column 'Count'. I mean, what I would to do is to produce these values, not just to sort them. Additionally, I appreciate your efforts in the efficiency, as I'm working on a 6 million rows table.

Comment: @Alfons That's what the logic does, it essentially groups your rows by [Code] value and then gives them an incrementally increasing int value for each row ordered by [Date] so if you had five date values (1,6,9,13,22) for [Code] value 25 the date 1 would get a 1 [Count] value, the 6 date would get a 2, 9 a 3, etc. It would get you exactly what you're asking for. If you can use windowed functions this takes care of you.

Comment: @Alfons I know that you do not have a column called `Count`. In all of these queries, I derive that column. You should be able to test them against your table to validate that I haven't assumed you have a column that you don't...

Comment: Hi again @AaronBertrand, I am looking for an upgrade of this code. Considering that in the 'Date' column (in yyyy/mm format) I have several dates which may be repeated, how should I modify the code to produce that count only for a time frame of 'n' months?. Additionally, this time frame should not be static. That is, I should be counting the number of occurrences of the last 'n' months.

Comment: @Alfons I think you should add a new question and make sure to include *real* sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a running count of the code values. If so, then you can use the following query to get a running count:

```
SELECT date,
  code, 
  (SELECT count(code)
   FROM yourtable b 
   WHERE b.date <= a.date
     and a.code = b.code) AS TotalCount
FROM yourtable a
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/280bc/1)

Or you can use:

```
SELECT a.date,
  a.code, 
  count(a.code) AS TotalCount
FROM yourtable a
cross join yourtable b
WHERE b.date <= a.date
  and a.code = b.code
group by a.date, a.code
order by a.date;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/280bc/6)

Note, this will work fine on smaller tables but on larger tables there will be issues. (Thanks @AaronBertrand)

Comment: On a small table these will work ok, but they will not scale. Reads will go through the roof as the number of rows increases.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly you want to add extra column that will tell you how many times that Code occurred.

```
select *, 
COUNT(1) over (partition by Code) 
from Table
```

Comment: This produces the same count for all instances of a specific code. They want a running count, e.g. first instance of 25 = 1, second instance of 25 = 2...

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand You absolutely right, I didn't quite get he wanted a running total.