# SQL keeping count of occurrences through a sliding window

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-server-2012

In the previous question (Please refer to: [SQL Keeping count of occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817239/sql-keeping-count-of-occurrences)) I needed to count the number of occurrences of a variable.

The code provided was as follows:

```
SELECT 
    [Date], Code, 
    [Count] = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY [Date] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM dbo.YourTable
ORDER BY [Date];
```

However, now I need to introduce an improvement to that code:

Let's say that I have the following table:

```
   Date          | Code
   ------------------------
   2010/01/01    | 25
   2010/01/01    | 22
   2010/01/01    | 23
   2010/01/01    | 25
   2010/01/02    | 23
   2010/01/02    | 23
   2010/01/03    | 23
   2010/01/04    | 23
   2010/01/05    | 23
   2010/01/06    | 23
   2010/01/07    | 23
   .....
   2013/03/02    | 21
```

Now, I need to count the number of occurrences in a specific period of time. The desired output would be as follows (supposing a time frame of n=2 days, for the sake of simplicity)

```
    Date         | Code  |  Occurrences
   ------------------------------------
   2010/01/01    | 25    |      1
   2010/01/01    | 22    |      1
   2010/01/01    | 23    |      1
   2010/01/01    | 25    |      2
   2010/01/02    | 23    |      2
   2010/01/02    | 23    |      3
   2010/01/03    | 23    |      3 -> We are not considering the occurence in 2011/01/01 as it is out of the scope now
   2010/01/04    | 23    |      2 -> Considers only occurrences in 01/03 and 01/04 
   2010/01/05    | 23    |      2
   2010/01/06    | 23    |      2
   2010/01/07    | 23    |      2
   .....
   2013/03/02    |  21   |      1
```

That is, I need to know how many times the code 'x' has appeared in my table in the last 'n' months.

This is run in SQL Server 2012.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of `SQL Server`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use option with [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), [CROSS APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator and [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) ranking function

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT [Date], Code
  FROM dbo.YourTable  
  GROUP BY [Date], Code
  )
  SELECT c.Date, c.Code, o.Occurrences
  FROM cte c 
    CROSS APPLY (
                 SELECT t2.[Date], t2.Code,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.[Date] ORDER BY t2.[Date]) AS Occurrences        
                 FROM dbo.YourTable t2
                 WHERE c.Code = t2.Code
                   AND DATEDIFF(day, t2.[Date], c.[Date]) BETWEEN 0 AND 1
                 ) o
  WHERE c.Code = o.Code AND c.[Date] = o.[Date] 
  ORDER BY c.[Date]
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cf8d8/1)

For improving performance use this index

```
CREATE INDEX x ON dbo.YourTable([Date], Code)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, it seems to work perfectly on the demo. Just one question: If I create the index, will I be able to copy the output table in a new table?

Comment: @Alfons what table :temporary, variable or existing table and why it is necessary to copy?

Comment: I want to copy the result of the query into a new table, as I will need to work with it and to use this information for other tables. The specific table that I need would be the result of the query, the one that is being produced in the sqlfiddle demo.

Comment: No problem, you can create an index on a table source, and if further is necessary to create a new index on the new table you can make it too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code,[Date] ORDER BY [Date]) AS NO,
            [Date], Code, 
            COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY Code ,[Date]) AS [Count] 
        FROM dbo.YourTable Where date between dateadd(m, -n, GETDATE()) and GETDATE() ) 
AS T1 WHERE No = 1
        ORDER BY [Date];
```

Or Try this.

```
 SELECT * FROM 
                (SELECT 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code,[Date] ORDER BY [Date]) AS NO,
                [Date], Code, 
                COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY Code ,[Date]) AS [Count] 
            FROM dbo.YourTable Where 
    Code = 25 And
    date between dateadd(m, -n, GETDATE()) and GETDATE() ) AS T1 WHERE No = 1
            ORDER BY [Date];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Code) Occurrences 
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Occurrences
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

**Query 1**:

```
select 
  count(*) as CountOccurance,
  code
from 
  tbl 
where 
  code = 21 and 
  date between dateadd(m, -5, SYSDATETIME ()) and SYSDATETIME ()
group by 
  code
```

**Results**:

```
| COUNTOCCURANCE | CODE |
-------------------------
|              1 |   21 |
```

If you want count for all the code values then remove the where clause..

### **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40a6f/11)**

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, it is not producing the desired output, unfortunately. In this case, I don't want to introduce a filter in the output (where date between .....), but to introduce this kind of filter through the calculation. I need, preserving the number of rows I have, to calculate the number of times that the code attached to the date (note that dates are repeated) appears in the previous 'n' months. I hope the explanation of the problem is clearer now.

Comment: Didn't got you what you are saying..  You just need to add the `n` which indicates the number of months for which we have to search records..  If I am wrong can you show your desired output in tabular format...